# How do I render sass in a rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass

I have a Rails 3.2 app. I'm trying to render processed sass code in a partial.

I have added an initializer to handle scss files:

```
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :scss,
  Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate
```

My sass file is called _style.scss and the render call looks like:

```
<%= render partial: "./templates/default/style", formats: "css" %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `call' for Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate:Class
```

To me, this looks like Rails doesn't know how to handle the Sass file, however, any .scss files included in my application.css file are processed correctly so, at least in that context, I know sass processing works. I've experimented with different extensions and formats. In some cases I can get the view to render, but sass is not processed.

Comment: should you not be doing `stylesheet_include_tag` ?

Comment: @GauravShah stylesheet_link_tag will write a link, but sass will only be parsed if the file is in the assets directory and I would like to load it from a different location. (I'm looking at parsing sass outside the assets pipeline now.)

Comment: As pointed out in this answer to a similar question, rendering sass in a rails partial is not a good idea. The better approach is to generate the css code once, rather than parse sass code each time which is expensive.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908780/how-to-use-sass-as-a-template-handler-for-views-in-rails-3

I will leave the question open since I'm still curious if this can be done, but I am changing my approach.

Comment: I'm interested in this because I'm building an AMP page which requires style to not be linked from an external file (annoyingly)

Answer (score 2):

I created a helper method to do this

```
def render_scss(file)
  text = render("/amp/#{file}")
  view_context = controller.view_context

  engine = Sass::Engine.new(text, {
    syntax: :scss, cache: false, read_cache: false, style: :compressed,
    sprockets:  {
      context:     view_context,
      environment: view_context.assets_environment
    }
  })
  raw engine.render
end
```

(Note: this includes the sprockets context to be able to handle the asset pipeline within your sass).

And then you call it like so (the scss is kept in a partial in the same directory called _amp.css.scss - not in the assets directory):

```
<style>
  <%= render_scss("amp.css.scss") %>
</style>
```

(Obviously this works for scss - but it's easy to change to apply to sass)

```
def render_sass(file)
  text = render("/amp/#{file}")
  view_context = controller.view_context

  engine = Sass::Engine.new(text, {
    syntax: :sass, cache: false, read_cache: false, style: :compressed,
    sprockets:  {
      context:     view_context,
      environment: view_context.assets_environment
    }
  })
  raw engine.render
end
```

The problem with this approach is that it it parsed at run time, however this can be got around by using standard Rails caching.

e.g.

```
<% cache(my_object) do %>
  <style>
    <%= render_scss("amp.css.scss") %>
  </style>
<% end %>
```

**Note**: in most normal situations you'll want to keep your stylesheets in a separate file. However there can be situations where this isn't appropriate. For example, I'm using this technique to build [Google AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) pages where they forbid the stylesheet to be in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing**

I think the problem will likely be to do with *parsing*

As you're calling a *partial*, Rails will typically try and render the pure `HTML` in the browser, with embedded `erb` code. If you're trying to call a `css` file in this way, I can only think that Rails will be unable to process the `css` in the same way

--

As mentioned in the comments, I would certainly use [`stylesheet_link_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag), as this will point to your CSS file in your HTML (which is how browsers process this anyway)

If you wanted to *output* the CSS itself, you'll have to define it inside an HTML file & then output that using a [`partial`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) (as you're trying to do now)

Comment: I am trying to output the CSS itself in a partial. (Your last comment.) The suggestion to use stylesheet_link_tag is ok, but unfortunately it only parses sass in the assets directory. If I can figure out how to parse sass outside the assets dir, that will work.

Comment: My understanding with partials is that parsing should occur based on the extensions, so _style.scss should be parsed as sass and then returned. I tried renaming the file _style.html.scss and using  render with formats: "html" but I still get "undefined method `call' for Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate:Class" so it looks like Rails doesn't know how to parse sass outside of the assets pipeline.